# Uploading multiple files with metadata

Tags: 2010, managed-metadata, file-upload

We want to upload many files from our file server to SharePoint2010. We want to add the metadata within, or before the upload.

Can somebody give me a good advice on how to handle that this?
Is there any software? Give it some code or something else.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Powershell scripts to upload documents and apply metadata to them. Here is codeplex project [SharePoint Multiple File Upload Script](https://spfileupload.codeplex.com/) which does exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

There are third party products to do this as an end user who does not have access to Powershell. We've just started using Metavis Information Manager and it does a good job to bulk upload and bulk classify documents. It also allows to retain the original creation date and author of the document, so SharePoint shows that a doc was created last January by Joe Bloggs, instead of today by me, just because I uploaded it today.

Answer (score 1):

We offer a tool called Lacun Drop It. It does exactly what you are looking for: you can drag and drop a lot of files at once and it then opens a wizard that walks you through all the metadata per file. You can copy existing or add new metadata.

Give it a try, there's a free trial: https://www.lacunsolutions.com/lacun/lacun-drop-it-detail

Answer (score 1):

you can try 3-rd party solution. For example, [Virto Bulk File Upload](http://www.virtosoftware.com/products/bulk/virto-bulk-file-upload).
Also, there is free solution on msdn website: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Load-Bulk-Content-to-3f379974